# How to add permission params to getLoginUrl() in php sdk 3.1.1

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

How do i add permission parameters to getLoginUrl() in php sdk 3.1.1?

```
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build an array of extended permissions and call within getLoginUrl.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

```
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
    $params = array(
      "scope"        => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,offline_access',
      "redirect_uri" => 'Redirect_URL'
    );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
```

Comment: `scope` and `redirect_uri` keys of the array need to be in quotes of course!